# VMware Player "Manage > Install VMware Tools..." is Disabled

Tags: vmware-player, vmware-tools

> Note: I will be answering this question myself to help other people
>   who come across this problem in the future. Feel free to submit your
>   own answers if you want, but know that it's already answered!

I am attempting to install the VMware Tools in a Windows 8.1 guest, but the `Manage > Install VMware Tools...` menu bar button is greyed out. I have downloaded the VMware tools for Windows (I can see it in `C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Player\windows.iso`) on the host computer. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 23):

Even though it seems obvious now, the issue was that the Windows 8.1 guest did not recognize a CD/DVD drive. I had to add one manually in the virtual machine settings. I also found that although the `Manage > Install VMware Tools...` menu button was then enabled, I still had to manually mount the `windows.iso` file in the CD drive for the VMware Tools to display in "This Computer". Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: For info: same issue and solution with a Windows 10 guest.

Comment: +1 for no CD/DVD drive installed in a recently P2V'd image. Duuur.

Comment: Never occurred to me that I needed to have a virtual DVD drive to be able to install the VM Tools.  In retrospect, makes sense.

Comment: Ok, in my case, for a new Win 10 machine, I needed to apply two solutions: change Proxy settings in File->Preferences to "No proxy", and remove the CD/ROM, shutdown the machine, add a new CD/ROM and start again the manchine.
Only in the sequence I was able to activate the option.

Answer (score 2):

For me what worked was to change the Floppy disk type to "physical". It doesn't make any sense because I obviously don't have a floppy disk connected to my laptop, but [this post](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/06/21/install-vmware-tools-disabled/) suggested it, and it worked.