# "Install vmware tools" grayed out windows 8.1 guest, Linux host vmware workstation 12

Tags: vmware-workstation

The "install vmware tools" is grayed out in windows 8.1 guest, Linux host vmware workstation 12.

I tried the suggestion in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/960352/vmware-player-manage-install-vmware-tools-is-disabled) link with no success

I have tried starting windows with cd/dvd not connected (this results in an empty cd/dvd drive showing under my devices in the windows 8.1 guest but "install vmware tools" still grayed out)

I have tried starting the windows guest without the cd/dvd and then going to vm / removable devices / connect

I have tried ejecting the cd/dvd from within windows (the iso used to install is in the directory by default, there is no option I can see to mount a empty virtual cd/dvd) but "install vmware tools" is still grayed out

I have tried re-installing windows to see if that would bring up the option

How can i get vmware tools install working?

Or better yet, how can i skip the problematic interface and download vmware tools for windows 8.1 guest from within windows and then install it?

[see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsxst.png)

Comment: Can you provide a link to a screenshot that shows your CD/DVD drive is successfully mounted? As well as show us a `df` or `mount` command output to see what devices are mounted via the host?

Comment: hello, i've updated my post to show a link to pic showing visual and terminal data showing drive is mounted. Linked because embedded pics are not enabled for my account.

Comment: Also, running the df and mount command on the host does not show virtual devices mounted in guest unless i map those drives

Comment: Try [this](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/463493?start=0&tstart=0) suggestion by `shaunm2`

Comment: @DrZoo thanks for the tip. I tried it as regular user and root with reboots and workstation restarts. I also tried toggling proxy settings while guest was running with no luck.

Comment: I came across a decent sounding suggestion. When you installed the Guest OS, did you specify that it was a Windows machine or did you happen to select the option called `Other`?

Comment: I specified it was a windows machine. Under the machine properties it also shows that the machine type is Microsoft Windows. Maybe I should toggle that to other and back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35505/discussion-between-drzoo-and-jtlindsey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon moving to the chat a solution was found. I mentioned manually downloading the `.iso` and try installing it like that. It ended up doing the trick.

**Steps performed by jtlindsey** - I manually downloaded the .iso on my host machine, went into my windows guest machine settings and set cd/dvd to the path of my .iso, booted windows and launched the vmware tools and installed like normal.

It also appears that the VMWare Tools `.iso` Archive is tricky to find via Google search so below is a link for those who may come across this question in the future.

[VMWare Tools Archive](https://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/index.html)